# Why is taking the Imaginary or Real part of $e^{ix}$ allowed when solving for a particular solution in a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

When we have a differential equation such as

$y''-2y'+y = \sin(x)$

We have to solve it by finding the general solution to the respective homogenous equation

In this case one can see right away it is

$(Ax+b)e^x$

And we have to find a particular solution to the non homogenous equation.

$y''-2y'+y=\sin(x)$

Now the strategy that I am being taught to use, is to find the answer to another equation of the same form

$y'' - 2y' + y = e^{ix}$ and then take the appropriate part, in this case it would be the imaginary part as we have $\sin(x)$

Why is this allowed, how is it guaranteed that solving e^ix and evaluating the appropriate part will give a particular solution to the respective differential equation

Is it because the constants are linear? Are there any cases in which this strategy would fail?

Comment: If there are real functions $f,g$, then differentiating $f(x)+ig(x)$ gives $f'(x) + ig'(x)$. i.e. The imaginary part of this derivative is the same function as the derivative of the imaginary part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of linearity of the derivative. Let
$f(x) = a(x)+ i b(x)$, where $a, b$ are functions from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, be a solution to a differential equation of the form $c_0f + c_1f' + c_2f''...c_nf^{(n)} = g$ (where the $c_i$ are real-valued functions). Then since $f'(x) = a '(x) + ib'(x)$, we have

$$Re(g(x)) = Re(c_0f + c_1f' + c_2f''...c_nf^{(n)}) = Re(c_0f) + Re(c_1f')...Re(c_nf^{(n)}) = $$
$$c_0Re(f) + c_1Re(f')...c_nRe(f^{(n)}) = c_0a + c_1a'...c_na^{(n)}$$

because, as above, $Re(f^{(n)}) = Re(f)^{(n)} = a^{(n)}$. It's important that the functions $c_i$ are real-valued, or we wouldn't be able to move them in and out of the $Re()$ function and the imaginary part of $f(x)$ might contribute to the real part of the entire expression.